# Google maps hide/display issue

Tags: google-maps

I am using IONIC framework (though I am not sure that's relevant) and have a view where the user can toggle between map and list mode.  The issue is that if the initial mode is list, and the user toggles, the map is cropped/messed up.  But if the initial mode is the map itself, all is well. I have a codepen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPrvRG - to illustrate the issue I am experiencing.  It's set to map mode right now, but you can change this line

```
$scope.viewMode = 'Map';
```

to

```
$scope.viewMode = 'List';
```

to see the problem.  Any ideas why this is happening or how to fix/get around it?

Comment: Here is another codepen that strips away all the IONIC stuff, and demonstrates the issue by simply hiding/unhiding the map div at initialization - http://codepen.io/heems/pen/Kwbojm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the changeViewMethod to

```
function changeViewMode (){
if (viewMode == 'Map'){
    document.getElementById('map-canvas').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('list-canvas').style.display = 'block';
    viewMode = 'List';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('map-canvas').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('list-canvas').style.display = 'none';
    viewMode = 'Map';
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644));
  }
}
```

And that solved the issue in the second (pure maps) Codepen.

Answer (score 0):

Update: With regards to the original codepen, I tried the

```
 google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

method in the switch mode method, but it didn't work.  I think the issue is with ng-show.  Some how it's not doing its rendering before the resize gets to do its thing.  On a hunch, I delayed the resize even (by say 20ms) using the $timeout service.

```
$timeout(function(){
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');            
    }, 100);
```

Now the map shows properly.  Not sure this is the best answer, but only one working so far.

Ps: in general ng-show seems to have performance issues which is the core problem.  I see lots of flicker using it for show items when going in and out of views.  I have had to resort to ng-if where possible as it doesn't exhibit that flicker issue.